# Creating Unity Asset bundles at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I have a windows application which users can import fbx models into. What I want to do is to be able to create asset bundle from these imported fbx models and then save the bundle file to a server. I wanted to ask if such thing is possible with unity. I have searched for answers but couldn't find any , there were some similar threads but none was exactly addressing this.
I'll appreciate if someone can help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/47870/26227 . I believe this answers your question